Border rendering is not supported by sequencer (Render Region not the issue)
I've been having a problem that only popped up yesterday.
I was working on my model and suddenly I got the "Border rendering is not supported by sequencer" error. I looked up solutions online and it said to turn off the render region, so I did.
However, when I then went to render my scene, all I got in the output was a texture file that I had used in the model. I copied over every object and my camera to a new Blender file and then it worked for another 12 hours until the same error and the same problem appeared. Does anyone know what the issue could be, and does anyone know what could solve it that isn't "uncheck the Render Region box"?
I'm on Blender 4.1.0 beta so I'm aware this could be a beta bug, but I still want to make sure. I'm on it so I can use EEVEE-Next.

This question is similar to: Render result is completely blank. The reason #4 given in the answer applies here. You cannot render using the Render Region because the Sequencer does not support it. Which would be no problem if you would not use the Sequencer, but it will be used automatically (unless disabled in Post Processing) as soon as there is a strip in the sequence editor which is most likely the texture file that gets rendered. It that is not the problem it might be better to upload your file.

@GordonBrinkmann I'd completely forgotten I used it. Thank you so much.
